# Unable to create checkSum value using SHA-256

Tags: java, hash, java-8, checksum

As per my requirement I want to create checksum value using SHA-256, from InputStream,

As below:

```
private InputStream createZipInput(List<ResponsePack> aList, byte[] manifestData)
    {
        final int bufferSize = 2048;
        byte buffer[] = new byte[bufferSize];
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ZipOutputStream zipFileToSend = new ZipOutputStream(byteStream);
        LOG.trace("Compressing the file {}");
        try
        {
            for (ResponsePack info : aList)
            {
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteStreamCheckSum = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ZipOutputStream zipFileToSendCheckSum = new ZipOutputStream(byteStreamCheckSum);
                zipFileToSend.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(info.getFileName()));
                zipFileToSendCheckSum.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(info.getFileName()));
                InputStream in = info.getFileContentStream();
                int length;
                while ((length = in.read(buffer)) >= 0)
                {
                    zipFileToSend.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    zipFileToSendCheckSum.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                zipFileToSend.closeEntry();
                zipFileToSendCheckSum.closeEntry();
                String checksum = validChecksum(byteStreamCheckSum.toByteArray());
                LOG.error("Checksum {}", checksum);
                zipFileToSendCheckSum.flush();
                zipFileToSendCheckSum.close();
            }
            zipFileToSend.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            return e;
        }
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(byteStream.toByteArray());
    }
    
    private static String validChecksum(byte[] dataCopy)
    {
        printLOG("Byte Array Size {}", dataCopy.length);
        try (ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(dataCopy)))
        {
            ZipEntry zipEntry;
            MessageDigest digest = DigestUtils.getSha256Digest();
            DWriter writer = new DWriter(digest);
            while ((zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null)
            {
                org.apache.commons.io.output.ByteArrayOutputStream dest = StreamUtils.extractFileAsByteArrayStream(zipInputStream);
                LOG.error("CheckSum Entity creating");
                if(zipEntry != null)
                {
                    printLOG("CheckSum Entity file Name {}", zipEntry.getName());
                }
                LOG.error("Byte array size {}", dest.toByteArray().length);
                writer.write(dest.toByteArray());
                dest.flush();
                dest.close();
            }
            
            if (writer.getChecksum() != null)
            {
                return writer.getChecksum();
            }
            else
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            printLOG("Exception encountered while creating checksum: {}", e.getMessage());
            return "";
        }
    }
    
    static class DWriter
    {
        private final MessageDigest myDigest;

        DWriter(MessageDigest digest)
        {
            myDigest = digest;
        }

        public void write(byte[] data)
        {
            myDigest.update(data);
        }

        public String getChecksum()
        {
            return new String(Hex.encodeHex(myDigest.digest()));
        }
    }
```

But the problem is when I checked the log, found byte array contains value but still checksum always creating for empty string, as below

```
Byte Array Size 3948
CheckSum Entity creating
CheckSum Entity file Name 20200911104812526.json
Byte array size 20854
Checksum e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
```

Help me where I am doing wrong, due to which I am getting checksum for an empty string

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's wrong with the code but it seems overly complicated: you're writing the input into a zipped stream and the dezip it in memory to read it again.

You don't need to do that: storing the input in a (non-zipped) byte array should be enough.

I think you need to make sure that in.read() works as intended (and that there's actually some data to read).
You get the checksum for a null input and your zip entry is also empty, so it looks like the input was empty. Add some logs or use a debugger to investigate what's happening.

```
private InputStream createZipInput(List<ResponsePack> aList, byte[] manifestData) {
    final int bufferSize = 2048;
    byte buffer[] = new byte[bufferSize];
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ZipOutputStream zipFileToSend = new ZipOutputStream(byteStream);
    LOG.trace("Compressing the file {}");
    try {
        for (ResponsePack info : aList) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteStreamCheckSum = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            zipFileToSend.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(info.getFileName()));
            InputStream in = info.getFileContentStream();
            int length;
            while ((length = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                zipFileToSend.write(buffer, 0, length);
                byteStreamCheckSum.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            zipFileToSend.closeEntry();
            
            MessageDigest digest = DigestUtils.getSha256Digest();
            digest.update(byteStreamCheckSum.toByteArray());
            String checksum = new String(Hex.encodeHex(digest.digest()));
            
            LOG.error("Checksum {}", checksum);
            
        }
        zipFileToSend.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw e;
    }
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(byteStream.toByteArray());
```